How to prove $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x}dx = \frac{1}{4}\ln(1- \frac{4}{s^2})$ using Tonelli-Fubini
I need some help with in trying to prove that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-sx}\,\frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x}\,{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(1- \frac{4}{s^{2}}\right)
\quad\mbox{using}\ Tonelli\mbox{--}Fubini
$$
Now, by Tonelli-Fubini we have that :
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^1 e^{-sx}{\sin(2xy)}dydx = \int_0^1\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}{\sin(2xy)}dxdy
$$
After some calculation, we find that
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^1 e^{-sx}{\sin(2xy)}dydx = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x}dx
$$
$$
\mbox{Now we need to prove that}\
\int_0^1\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}{\sin(2xy)}dxdy =
\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(1- \frac{4}{s^2}\right)
$$
This is when I need help : How can I show this equality? I have been thinking but I cannot come up with anything. I will appreciate some help.

Do you know the laplace transform of sine? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace_Transform_of_Sine

applying two times integration by parts, you can solve $\int e^{ax}\sin (bx)dx$

I think you mean $\frac14\ln(1\color{blue}{+}\tfrac{4}{s^2})$.

Use Euler representation of $\sin(bx)$
